# How to parse twitter feed data using json.reads(line)

Tags: python, json, twitter

I've downloaded a big stream of twitter data in JSON format and saved it to a text file. I now want to read it in, line by line, and decode it into a dictionary using `json.reads()`.

My only problem is that it throws an error on the first line, which I assume means the function doesn't think the data is JSON? I have added the line I want to decode at the bottom of this post. When I just print the lines the code works fine, its only the `json.reads()` function that throws an error.

Here is the code:

```
def decodeJSON(tweet_data): 
    for line in tweet_data:
        parsedJSON = json.loads(line)
        print(parsedJSON) # I just want to print for now to confirm it works.
```

Here is the error:

```
 File "/Users/cc756/Dropbox/PythonProjects/TwitterAnalysisAssignment/tweet_sentiment.py", line 17, in analyseSentiment
    parsedJSON = json.loads(line)   File "/Users/cc756/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Users/cc756/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/Users/cc756/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the first string:

```
'b\\'{"delete":{"status":{"id":805444624881811457,"id_str":"805444624881811457","user_id":196129140,"user_id_str":"196129140"},"timestamp_ms":"1500994305560"}}\\''
```

I feel like it should work, I've been staring at this for an hour with no improvement!

Comment: Is that exactly what the output of the first line looks like? `json.loads` isn't going to be able to parse that.

Comment: @CoryMadden b'{"delete":{"status":{"id":805444624881811457,"id_str":"805444624881811457","user_id":196129140,"user_id_str":"196129140"},"timestamp_ms":"1500994305560"}}'

Comment: Thats exactly what I pulled from the twitter feed and saved :s It seems to have changed slightly copying it from pycharm to the question but I just got that from the text file.

Comment: @ChrisCollins Don't put code/data in comments. Edit your question and format it accordingly to make it easier to read.

Comment: @ChrisCollins with that string I was able to use json.loads just fine. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings are in the wrong format. I'm not sure what you need to do to get rid of the `'b\\'`(which doesn't really make sense) at the beginning, but manually typing it in to the shell gives me this:

```
In [119]: json.loads(b'{"delete":{"status":{"id":805444624881811457,"id_str":"80
     ...: 5444624881811457","user_id":196129140,"user_id_str":"196129140"},"time
     ...: stamp_ms":"1500994305560"}}')
Out[119]: 
{u'delete': {u'status': {u'id': 805444624881811457,
   u'id_str': u'805444624881811457',
   u'user_id': 196129140,
   u'user_id_str': u'196129140'},
  u'timestamp_ms': u'1500994305560'}}
```

Sorry, I'd make a comment, but imagine this post in a comment... :)

I'm not sure what's up with your pasting of the string into the question, but it's following an invalid format for Python, so you may want to correct that.

UPDATE: The issue was that the data was in binary format and just needed to be decoded with `data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! So thats odd. You say using the string I posted in the comment to my original question json.loads() worked fine... Does that mean its loading into python incorrectly? I'm using open() to open the text file and then just using a for loop which iterates through each line.. confusing!

Comment: Yea, it *could* be the `\\\`` if that's actually a part of the string that loads. I recommend printing the line before you try calling `json.loads` on to make sure that it is indeed a valid JSON line and it's not trying to pass an empty string to the function. You could get rid of that with `line.replace("\\", "")`

Comment: I'm getting somewhere if I delete the first and last 2 characters from the string.. Its odd that theyre there

Comment: It's probably just meant as a separator so you can open the entire file and split it on the slashes. For example `lines = file.read(); tweet_data = lines.split('\\')`

Comment: aha! Its binary encoding! I am using python3.6 and it reads the data in binary mode. I need to use json.loads(line.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: oh yea, that's what the `b` at the beginning of the string means, but the `\\`'s get removed when you decode it?

Comment: Yep! I had to decode the data returned by the json request into UTF-8 and then save it. Otherwise it loads into the code as a string but is still in binary. Hopefully this saves someone else from the confusion of trying to do data scraping in python3 when all the tutorials are in python 2.7!

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you got it. I updated my post to reflect that for the future people.